# After applying google web font, a part of the background was removed. What should I do?

Tags: html, css

My navigation bar has image as the background, and consists of buttons with nested links. When I applied Google web font, a square part of my nav bar background has been removed.

How can I fix this? :)

```
nav { 
  padding: 0; 
  word-spacing: 5em; 
  background: url("bgbutton.jpg"); 
  border-radius: 50px; 
  float: center; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  border: 2px white solid; 
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #FF0000; 
  text-align: justify; 
}

nav ul { list-style: none; } 
nav li { display: inline; } 
nav a  { color:white; text-decoration: none; }

.buttonsnav button{
  background: url("bgbutton.jpg"); 
  background-size: cover; 
  width: 200px; height: 100px; 
  border-radius: 60px; 
}
```

Comment: Daniel, welcome to Stackoverflow. I would love to help you but without any HTML or minimal code to reproduce the problem, I'm guessing in the dark. Could you add enough code to make an example?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you want but you can try using flexbox to style your nav element. below is a link to codepen with an example. i hope this will help you. Also you may have missed a closing div somewher so do inspect your code to see for any missing closing tag or div 
https://codepen.io/salinaacharya/pen/MLWYXz

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="buttonsnav"><button><a>menu item</a></button</li>
    <li class="buttonsnav"><button><a>menu item</a></button</li>
    <li class="buttonsnav"><button><a>menu item</a></button</li>
    <li class="buttonsnav"><button><a>menu item</a></button</li>  
  </ul>
</nav>

nav { 
  padding: 0; 
  word-spacing: 5em; 
  background: url("https://alpha.aeon.co/images/bbee6475-5040-45b8-bc44-10c87ec7e3e3/header_essay-final-nyc42995.jpg"); 
  border-radius: 50px; 
  float: center; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  border: 2px white solid; 
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #FF0000; 
  text-align: justify; 
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

nav ul { list-style: none; } 
nav li { display: inline; } 
nav li a  { 
  color:white; 
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.buttonsnav button{
  background: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTl-x8faEwvXoLlaqrLnrZtzZZtFcdZSIC-fAeIpaCwYW8wByFV"); 
  background-size: cover; 
  width: 200px; height: 100px; 
  border-radius: 60px; 
}
```

Comment: Thank  you. I'm going to try to implement your solution soon.

Comment: Cool. let me know how you go or if you come with any other issue

Comment: It didnt work. Here is print screen of how the navbar looks https://imgur.com/a/S2omh8f , I have no idea how to fix it :/

Comment: it looks like your nav bar and the body bg is having same background-image. try to give a higher z-index to the nav element. Would you also like to post your code again